# Good model for laravel app connecting to external databases

Tags: php, database, laravel, model-view-controller

I am using laravel 5 to write an internal application, it has its own database which can be managed by Laravel itself. I would like to ask questions on best practice of its architectural design.

The application should connect to a number of external systems which I have no control of and get data, via both those Application API and direct database connections. There are at lease 3 types of those external systems, and each type can be up to 3 instance of the same kind which requires same class and libraries to handle while the user selects which instance they would like to deal with.

The old version of this program was on some sort of CMS with ACL, and those external database credentials are stored in the program database and connections are sort of dynamically created after user selection. The original application has classes for each for handling data for each external  system, and those classes are stored as "libraries" in the code. it is sort of Object oriented, meaning that I created that class instance in the code and use this object to get data...

So in Laravel, how is the best practice, my questions and concerns are: 
1. Is it possible to move those classes to Laravel program? Or should I write a new architecture? 
2. As I do not want the external system databases get accidentally modified,  how should those database queries be handled to provide the best protection to that? Those database does not belong to this application, it is just external data sources. I would be setting those data base user as readonly, but I don't want occasion accidents like misconfiguration of permissions causing any problems.

Comment: Look at this, is that some thing you want http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections